# ReactJS: Intercommunication between two dropdowns

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop two dropdowns in ReactJS component, The second dropdown values depend on first dropdown value. 
If first dropdown value changes, second dropdown values changes based on first dropdown value. Like Countries and States.
The following is the code snippet. can you help me how to implement.

Thanks

```
<script type="text/jsx">
/*** @jsx React.DOM */
var data = [
  {key:"eStatements", value:"eStatements"},
  {key: "mobileApp", value:"Mobile App"},
  {key: "billPay", value:"Bill Pay"},
  {key: "remoteDeposit", value:"Remote Deposit"},
  {key: "onlineBanking ", value:"Online Banking"},
  {key: "P2P", value:"P2P"}
];
var myOptions = [];

var DropdownApp = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectApp data={this.props.data} name={this.props.name}/>
      </div>

    );
  }
});

var SelectApp = React.createClass({
  getInitialState:function(){
      return {myOptions : {"signUp" : "Sign Up"}};
  },
    handleSelectChange : function(e){
      var product = e.target.value;
      if("eStatements" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "signUp" , value: "Sign Up"}];
      } else if("Mobile App" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "noOfLogins" , value:  "Number of Logins"}];
      } else if("Bill Pay" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "noOfPayments" , value:  "Number of Payments"},{key:  "addNewPayeeAndPay" , value:  "Add New Payee"}];
      } else if("Remote Deposit" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "noOfDeposits" , value:  "Number of Deposits"}];
      } else if("Online Banking" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "noOfLogins" , value:  "Number of Logins"}];
      }else if("P2P" == product) {
        myOptions = [{key: "noOfPayments" , value:  "Number of Payments"}, {key: "addNewPayeeAndPay" , value:  "Add New Payee"}];
      }
      this.setState({myOptions: myOptions});
    },
    render: function(){
      var opt = this.props.data.map(function(d){
        return (<OptionsApp key={d.key} value={d.value}/>);
      });
        return (
          <div>
          <div>
            <select name={this.props.name} id={this.props.name} onChange={this.handleSelectChange}>
            {opt};
            </select>
          </div>
          <div>
            <select name={this.state.myOptions} >
            {opt};
            </select>
          </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    });

    var OptionsApp = React.createClass({
      render : function(){
          return (
              <option value={this.props.key}> {this.props.value}</option>
          );
      }
    });
React.renderComponent(<DropdownApp data={data} name="my name"/>, document.getElementById("dropDown"))

</script>
```

Comment: If your options are depended on each other like countries and states, you could structure data easily as an object. With e.g. the countries as keys and for every country an array of e.g. states as the value. The first select then renders the value from `Object.keys(data)` and the second one the corresponding value `data[key]`. Simply updating the second on `onChange` of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

If two components need to communicate, that may be a sign that they should be siblings.

If you wrap multiple components in a parent component, you can use some of the above strategies in combination to facilitate communication between them.

```
class ParentComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SiblingA
          myProp={this.state.propA}
          myFunc={this.siblingAFunc.bind(this)}
          />
        <SiblingB
          myProp={this.state.propB}
          myFunc={this.siblingBFunc.bind(this)}
          />
      </div>
    );
  }
  // Define 'siblingAFunc' and 'siblingBFunc' here 
}
```

http://andrewhfarmer.com/component-communication/#5-parent-component